# Check if a javascript file is already loaded on a page

Tags: c#, javascript, scriptmanager, registerclientscriptblock

How to check in C# if a javascript file is already loaded on to the page? Let's say I have a user control in a different namespace that I load on to a page. I would like to see if a script file doesn't exist before I register it with the scriptmanager.

Comment: How are you registering the script on the page?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424073/how-to-determine-if-a-javascript-was-already-loaded-by-other-html-file

Comment: it is a script tag on master page and the user control has no idea about the master page.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for 
[ScriptManager.GetRegisteredClientScriptBlocks()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.getregisteredclientscriptblocks.aspx). From that collection of RegisteredScript objects you can use the Type and Key properties to uniquely identify them.