# What happens if you call jQuery $.getScript('myscript.js') twice?

Tags: jquery

I'm caching ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```

And I want to know, if I call a script that's already been loaded, will it load a second time or not?

```
$.getScript('js/jquery.colorbox-min.js');
```

Thanks!

Comment: related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424073/how-to-determine-if-a-javascript-was-already-loaded-by-other-html-file

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer that is simply look at the http requests through [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). However, [jquery.colorbox.js](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) should not misbehave even if it is loaded twice.

Answer (score 1):

It does download it twice. You can see it in Firebug